# Django Rest Framework: Add a method to Serializer and ListSerializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

Say I have a serializer like this:

```py
from rest_framework import  serializers

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     @property
     def html_attrs(self):
         return f'bar="{self.bar}"'
```

```py
# view
instance = Foo.objects.first()
context['serializer'] = MySerializer(instance)

# template.html
{{ serializer.html_attrs }}
```

That works, but if I have multiple items, this does not work (seems like the ListSerializer does get the property method):

```py
# view
bar = 123 # value of bar from url params
instances = Foo.objects.filter(bar=bar).all()  # all instance have same bar value
context['serializer'] = MySerializer(instances, many=True)

# template.html
{{ serializer.html_attrs }}
```

As the above raises:

```
*** AttributeError: 'ListSerializer' object has no attribute 'html_attrs'
```

Comment: Which is the error message that are you receiving?

Comment: @claudius I added the error message to the bottom of the question cheers

Answer (score 0):

Get the value from a single instance serializer, and attach it to the `ListSerializer`:

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):        
        # instances = args[0] if len(args) > 0 else kwargs['instance']
        # instance = instances[0]
        list_serializer_class = super().many_init(*args, **kwargs)
        serializer_class = list_serializer_class.child
        list_serializer_class.html_attrs = serializer_class.html_attrs
        return list_serializer_class
```